# filepicker.io mass convert image

Tags: filepicker.io

Is there a way to mass convert an image? We're experimenting with replacing imagemagick and taking the load off of our servers -- I've got a version working that just loops through the sizes and calls convert on the original image, making 23 copies of differing styles (sizes and crops). However, if the user leaves the page before all the conversions are done, the script stops and I end up missing a bunch of image styles.

Is there a good way to get around this with Filepicker.io? I'd really like to be able to just pass a list of options to the convert method and have it complete in the background.

Thanks in advance,
 
- Jeff

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is either using the /convert endpoint to do on-the-fly conversion  (https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#fpurl-images) or to do a POST to our rest endpoint  to create the converted images and store them in S3 via a server-side call